# pthread application carsh - No clue with GDB or strace

Tags: multithreading, crash, pthreads, posix, strace

I am running a Linux application on Ubunutu 14.04. I have I have 4 different threads running. Application is running as service and hangs infinitely after running for couple of days. I tried to use strace and gdb but no help at all.

When I run strace -p for each thread id (obtained using ps -efL), on each thread stuck at following

```
#sudo strace -p 17755
Process 17755 attached
futex(0x6f1be8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL
```

I run the gdb and attached on each thread. Back trace of each thread is same as follows

```
sudo gdb
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.7.1-0ubuntu5~14.04.3) 7.7.1
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
(gdb) attach 17755
Attaching to process 17755
warning: process 17755 is a cloned process
Reading symbols from /opt/smarteefi/bin/clserver...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.18...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.18
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.19.so...done.
done.
warning: File "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db-1.0.so" auto-loading has been declined by your `auto-load safe-path' set to "$debugdir:$datadir/auto-load".
To enable execution of this file add
    add-auto-load-safe-path /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db-1.0.so
line to your configuration file "/home/sfiadmin/.gdbinit".
To completely disable this security protection add
    set auto-load safe-path /
line to your configuration file "/home/sfiadmin/.gdbinit".
For more information about this security protection see the
"Auto-loading safe path" section in the GDB manual.  E.g., run from the shell:
    info "(gdb)Auto-loading safe path"
warning: Unable to find libthread_db matching inferior's thread library, thread debugging will not be available.
Loaded symbols for /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.19.so...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.19.so...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
Reading symbols from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files.so.2...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.19.so...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files.so.2
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_dns.so.2...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_dns-2.19.so...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_dns.so.2
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.19.so...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2
warning: File "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db-1.0.so" auto-loading has been declined by your `auto-load safe-path' set to "$debugdir:$datadir/auto-load".
warning: Unable to find libthread_db matching inferior's thread library, thread debugging will not be available.
0x00007f86a10eff2c in ?? ()
    at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S:147
   from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
147 ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) 
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007f86a10eff2c in ?? ()
    at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S:147
   from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

Comment: The information in this stack trace is very minimal, I doubt anyone can help with this.  It's possible there's some stack corruption going on.

Comment: >>It's possible there's some stack corruption going on<< How do I check if there is a stack corruption?

Comment: I'm looking at this trace again and I'm a little confused.  Did the program crash, or did it just hang?  It seems like it tried to jump to 0x0 which is always a segfault.  If that's what happened, the stack is definitely corrupted as there's only one frame here (but there should be many).  You can try using valgrind --tool=memcheck but I don't know how practical that is for a long-running program unless the bug surfaces early.

Comment: It just hanged. It didn't exit. Sorry for confusion created due to title

Comment: valgrind has caught a bug accessing already freed memory. Fixed it and now again running. Will see if that fixes the issue. @bchurchill Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Okay, good luck.  Sometimes valgrind bugs don't actually manifest themselves, so it's hard to say if that will actually fix the problem or not.  There might be something else too going on.

Comment: Because the threads are hanging on futex, it could also be a deadlock situation.

Comment: I fixed problem reported by valgrind but that didn't fix the issue. Now my binary is compiled with -fstack-protector-all  -fstack-check to see if there is any stack related error.  I am running this binary now with valgrind. No error reported by valgrind, neither any stack related error. But problem still persist (all thread hangs and in backtrace address at the bottom of stack is all zeros). Only difference was that this time there were more frames in the backtrace with gdb but at the bottom it was all zeros so problem remains same.

Comment: Also I would like to tell that one of the thread which was waiting in blocking recv() on a UDP socket to listen commands from my custom cli also shows same back trace (stuck in futex) even though it should not have come out from recv because no cli command was sent and it was a blocking call. This seems to be corruption but not getting any clue how to trouble shoot. I am in this situation for last 3 months and every time I have to restart application to get it working.

Comment: It sounds like the problem is a deadlock.  Are there multiple locks?  If so, are they always acquired/released in the same order?  If not, you can have deadlock.  For example, if there are threads A and B and locks X and Y, it's possible that A takes lock X and B takes lock Y.  If then A requests lock Y and B requests lock X before releasing them, you'll be stuck forever.  Is it possible to see which futex each thread is stuck in?